# How to use a custom compare tool with Perforce?

Tags: diff, compare, perforce, p4v, custom-tools

I have copy of [Grigsoft's Compare it!](http://www.grigsoft.com/) tool, can anyone tell me how to use it with 
Perforce source control?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In P4V, click the Edit->Preferences menu item to open the Preferences dialog.  Click "Diff" then select the "Other application" option then enter the path to your compare tool's executable.  Click OK and it will now use this tool for diffs.  You'll probably want to do the same thing for the default "Merge" application.

[image: P4V Preference dialog]